# C++ inconsistent foreground colors

Tags: c++, colors, coloring

I have started programming in C++ recently and have been testing using classes.
What I have noticed is that if I declare a variable before my methods like:

```
class Test {
    int value;
public:
    int getValue() const;
};
```

then the `public:` is not colorized. But if I don't write the `int value;` at all, then the `public:` is colored blue, making it stand out more.

This isn't just an error with `public:`, its a general rule error because having the following:

```
class Test {
private:
    int value;
public:
    int getValue() const;
};
```

will colorized `private:` but not `public:`. (Here the line `int value;` could still be removed and `public:` would still not be colored differently).

Is there a fix for this that I can put in my `$HOME/.emacs`?

Comment: Emacs is telling you that you shouldn't depend on default scope ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Emacs opens files ending in `.h` in C mode. If you would like to open them in C++ (where `private` and `public` will be highlighted as keywords), you can add the following to your init file:

```
(push '("\\.h\\'" . c++-mode) auto-mode-alist)
```

Or (even better):

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.h\\'" . c++-mode))
```

Comment: Do headers for actual C files still work the same with this?

Comment: No, my answer will make all headers open in C++ mode. Normally, this is fine as C++ is a superset of C. If you would like to have fine-grained control you can, for example, add `-*- C++ -*-` as a comment at the beginning of the file. This will make Emacs use C++ mode for that particular file.

Comment: @Lindydancer why use `push` instead of `add-to-list`?

Comment: @PythonNut, you're right, `add-to-list` is the better way to do this -- I've updated the answer. Thanks!